# How to secure a PDF with a password in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, pdf

I have developed a feature to export Personal Contact and data to PDF in Flutter and I want to seucre that data with a password or a PIN code set by the user when exporting the data to his/her email. Everything is set up and working fine, but I couldn't find a way to set a password to the exported PDF.
Here is my Widget Code, I am using PDF package 3.8.1.

```
import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart' as pw;
import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart' show Font;
import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart' as pwFonts;
import 'package:open_file/open_file.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

class PdfApi {
static Future<File> generateCenteredText() async{
final pdf = pw.Document();
pdf.addPage(My PDF Content here...);
return saveDocument(name: 'Personal Records.pdf', pdf: pdf);
}

static Future<File> saveDocument({
    required String name,
    required pw.Document pdf,
  }) async {
    final bytes = await pdf.save();
    final dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final file = File('${dir.path}/$name');
    await file.writeAsBytes(bytes);
     // secure the File with a PASSWORD or PIN code HERE....
    return file;
  }

}
```

I want a way to encrypt/secure the file with a password in Flutter before sending it via Email.

Comment: @KJ, how can I add password? the user will set his/her own password when exporting the PDF to their email.